# Can cosmological defects escape a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, magnetic-monopoles, cosmic-string, topological-defects

Based on my understanding, anything that can't move faster than light can't get out of a black hole, but space can since it can move faster than light (hence cosmic inflation is exponentiated).

Also, it seems to me that cosmological defects like cosmic strings, monopoles, etc are features of spacetime that contains the mass or energy instead of the mass/particles or energy itself. If this is true, does this mean cosmological defects can get out of the event horizon?

Comment: For *electric* monopoles, the answer is the [Reissner-Nordström metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charged_black_hole).

Comment: I don't know about magnetic monopoles or cosmic strings, but "Fast enough to escape a black hole" means something like "fast enough to get farther away from tomorrow". Since causality seems to work, I would guess the answer to your question is no.